NextJS 14 Build Error - Error occurred prerendering page
I'm running NextJS 14. During development (npm run dev) everything works ok.
However when I perform npm run build, I got the following error:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async i (C:\dev\next14\.next\server\app\admin\checklist\page.js:1:6403)
    at async n (C:\dev\next14\.next\server\app\admin\checklist\page.js:1:6569) {
  cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  digest: '2212964062'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/checklist". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async i (C:\dev\next14\.next\server\app\admin\checklist\page.js:1:6403)
    at async n (C:\dev\next14\.next\server\app\admin\checklist\page.js:1:6569)
 ✓ Generating static pages (16/16)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /admin/checklist/page: /admin/checklist

The admin/checklist/page is as below.
I have another page that is using the exact same function getCategories(), and they work fine. Only when I delete this page (admin/checklist/page)  then the npm run build is successful.
import React from 'react'
import { jsonHeaders } from '@/lib/const'

async function getCategories() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/user/category`, 
                            { 
                              headers: jsonHeaders,
                            })
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

const AdminChecklist = async () => {
  const data = await getCategories()
  
  return (
    <div>AdminChecklist</div>
  )
}

export default AdminChecklist


is the api a next js route handler

Show us the api code
